# creating new widget in odoo12 comunity

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

In a selfmade module in Odoo12ce there are some computed results and I want to write custom widget in order to put this result in red when it is under 0 and black more than 0.

the variable in the model:

```
result = fields.Float(string="Results", compute="calc_result")
```

and in the view:

```
<field name="result" widget="result_widget"/>
```

where result_widget is the new widget mentioned before, I really apreciate it if you guide me to write the module, beacuse the information I found on internet about it is very poor.

Answer (score 1):

What about a very simple solution by using the possible decorations?

```xml
<field name="result" decoration-danger="result < 0.0" />
```

Some other possible decorations are:

- decoration-bf
- decoration-it
- decoration-info
- decoration-muted
- decoration-primary
- decoration-success
- decoration-warning

IIRC these are changed to bootstrap text-decoration-* classes.

Comment: Interesting solution, I didn't know about the decoration classes :D, but it could be very helpfull to me to write custom widget because I want to use it also like a starting point to write more complex widgets.

Comment: Then look into some nice examples like the OCA [web_widget* modules](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/12.0) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to create a widget you need to understand how Javascript inheritance work in Odoo and that is explained clearly in the [Official Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_cheatsheet.html#creating-a-new-field-widget).

I will give you an example of how to proceed with the creation of a new widget field:

1. Create a file ***my_module/static/src/js/widget/result_field.js*** into that file place the code:

   ```
   odoo.define('my_module.result_field', function(require) {
      "use strict";
       var BasicFields= require('web.basic_fields');
       var FieldFloat = BasicFields.NumericField;
       var ResultFieldFloat;
       ResultFieldFloat= FieldFloat.extend({  
            /* NOW You are able to do as you wish*/                          
         _renderEdit: function () {
              // Override this function to modify your field editing
         }, 
         _renderReadonly: function () {
              // Override this function to modify your field on readonly mode
         },


         });

         // This is the name of your new widget field extending the Native Odoo NumericField
         Registry.add('my_result_widget', ResultFieldFloat);

         return {
               ResultFieldFloat: ResultFieldFloat,
         };
   });
   ```
2. Create a file ***my_module/views/my_module_view.xml***

   ```
       <odoo>
           <data>
               <record id="my_module_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
                    <field name="model">mymodule.model</field>
                    <field name="arch" type="XML">
                          <form string="Mymodule Form"> 
                                 <sheet>
                                    <field name="result" widget="my_result_widget" />
                                 </sheet>
                          </form>
                    </field>
               </record>
               <template id="my_module_fields_tpl" name="my_module_name assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
                       <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                           <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_module/static/src/js/widget/result_field.js" />
                       </xpath>
               </template>
           </data>
        </odoo>
   ```
3. Then in your manifest inside of data add your new view file.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I finally nailed it using your code and other snippets I found.